# Error in running gwt project with maven dependency using kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, eclipse-kepler

I am using Kepler 4.3.2 and Maven compiler plugin 3.1, GWT 2.6.1 plugin and Java 1.7 , Tomcat 7.0 using the following steps.

1. Create GWT project
2. Configure it into maven prject.
3. Add dependency in pom.xml.
4. Add module name in *.gwt.xml file.
5. Select project->properties->project facets-> dynamic web 3.0 and java 1.7.
6. Update maven project.
7. Fixing all the warnings and errors.

   Still I am having a problem to run the project that invalid thread excess Java NullPointerException.

I want to run this project on Jetty.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: any logs? any output? stack trace? anything that might help to localize the problem.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/monika0691/8f2c642c91b00c536a0d see the code here

Comment: There is no code, only pom and gwt.xml.